# How to log to the browser developer tools's console

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, log4net

I can't figure-out how to log to the browser developer tools's console with ASP.NET/Core, I tried several solutions but I'm still unable to show any log on the browser developer tools's console from my controller (I'm not talking about VS console).

Here is my code:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    public MyController(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<MyController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }


    private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger _logger;

    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {

        var myData = new MyData();

        Console.WriteLine("Test AAA");
        Debug.WriteLine("Test BBB");

        _logger.LogDebug("Logger Debug");
        _logger.LogInformation("Logger LogInformation");
        _logger.LogError("Logger LogError");
        _logger.LogTrace("Logger LogTrace");

        log.Info("This is a Info message");

        log.Warn("This is a Warning message");

        log.Error("This is an Error message");

        log.Fatal("This is a Fatal message");

        log.Debug("This is a Debug message");

        return Content(myData);
    }
}
```

How can I route these logs to the browser (Chrome/FireFox) Developer tools console?

Comment: The browser's console only shows log from code executed on the browser, there's nothing you can do on the server (your ApiController) that will log to the user's browser and any solution you find will involve passing the data from the server to the client and then logging it with javascript's console.log()

Comment: @eduardo-wada There isn't a way to route these logs from the server side to the client javascript's console.log() ? I need to include some messages to be shown in the browser's console when I call my Web API for debugging purpose.

Comment: you might create `webhook` to listen to logs

Answer (score 0):

Browser logs are done by executing javascript code that you return in that page. And even if it's doable i think it's not a thing you want to do.

Edit: But if you still want to do that you can create a custom view with a loginfo model and a small javascript script in the view. Something like this:

Model:

```
public class LogInfo
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Models.LogInfo
<script>console.log("@Model.Message");</script>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    LogInfo log = new  LogInfo {
    Message = "Hey Log"
};
    return View(log);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there isn't a way to redirect the logger's logs to the browser's console without the return? Because I'm using the return for returning other data and can't use it for the log!

Comment: @Wadjey why would you even need that in the first place?

Comment: @eduardo-wada For debugging purpose on the pre-production server. I want to be able to trace some issues when I call my REST api from the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

In function you've used to call Get() in Javascript/Ajax, add

```
console.log(return);
```

In the end of your Get() method, return Ok with your message

```
return Ok("This is Debug message");
```

Comment: I'm using the return Content(...) to return a required data, I can't use it to return the debug messages